# 'gpg.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command after setting environment?

Tags: maven, gnupg

> [INFO] --- maven-gpg-plugin:1.4:sign (sign-artifacts) @ server-test-toolkit ---
>   'gpg.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

I have set the environment path:

> *%SystemRoot%\system32;%SystemRoot%;%SystemRoot%\System32\Wbem;%SYSTEMROOT%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\MinGW\msys-7.2\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG*

I run the gpg in cmd.exe in windows, it is OK.

But when running the maven-gpg-plugin in eclipse why still popup the error:
'gpg.exe' is not recognized as an internal or external command,

Answer (score 4):

Rebooting solved the issue.

I guess the Maven runtinme didn't had his path updated after the GPG installation. Logging off and relogging may also be sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

when you receive this error message, “gpg is not recognized as an internal or external command” then you need to update your PATH variable.

To do this without reboot:

1. Open up a command prompt window
2. Paste this in:

   ```
   SET PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files (x86)\GNU\GnuPG
   ```
3. Hit Enter